# Read every line and display in a table PERL

Tags: perl, file, configuration, gentoo

I have a problem about perl. What I want is that I want to read my configuration file and display it in a table. Here is my configuration file looks like:

```
VID1
VID2
VID3
VID4
```

After I read all the line in the configuration file, I want it to be displayed in a table. How can I achieve this? I know I have to use loop to get all the line. Is that correct? Can anybody help me with this? Any help would be much appreciated. By the way, I'm new in perl. The read part is not the problem. The problem is on how to display them into a table.

**UPDATED**

[image: Example]

I want it be like this and so on. The border is 0 by the way. How can I read all those line and print it out like these?

**UPDATED**

Here is the output that I'm trying to get. The table is in a loop and display all the value after it reads from the configuration file.

[image: Example2]

Comment: The listing you gave looks like a table to me.  If you want formatted output, the least you can do is show what it should look like.

Comment: I've just updated my question. @Gene

Comment: @d.Grudder What do you include that image? Do you want to create an image?

Comment: @LeeDuhem No, it just a sample output. Sorry to make that as an image.

Comment: @d.Grudder That's not a table.  It's one line.  What should the table look like?

Comment: @d.Grudder What does your configure file really look like?

Comment: @LeeDuhem My configuration is like being shown above. I think i got this..maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sub print_line {
  my $source = shift;
  my $port = shift;
  my $ip = shift;
  format TABLE_FORMAT =
  Name of Video Source: @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        $source
     Local Port Number: @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        $port
Destination IP address: @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        $ip
.
  $~ = 'TABLE_FORMAT';
  write;
}

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print_line($_, 'example', 'example');
}
```